Unable to display mbtiles in a Leaflet map
I am trying an experiment to serve natural earth vector tiles which, as I understand, are in mapbox vector tile format. I downloaded the sqlite db called natural_earth.vector.mbtiles from https://github.com/lukasmartinelli/naturalearthtiles/releases/tag/v1.0 and set it up as a datasource. In my html file, I have the following simplest of code
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo=" crossorigin=""></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.vectorgrid@latest/dist/Leaflet.VectorGrid.bundled.js"></script>
<script type="module">
    const map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 1);
    L.vectorGrid.protobuf(`http://localhost:3000/{z}/{x}/{y}`).addTo(map);
</script>

I get the following error in my browser console
Uncaught Error: Unimplemented type: 3
    skip Leaflet.VectorGrid.bundled.js:767
    readFields Leaflet.VectorGrid.bundled.js:599
    VectorTileLayer$2 Leaflet.VectorGrid.bundled.js:1577
    readTile Leaflet.VectorGrid.bundled.js:1630
    readFields Leaflet.VectorGrid.bundled.js:597
    VectorTile$1 Leaflet.VectorGrid.bundled.js:1625
    _getVectorTilePromise Leaflet.VectorGrid.bundled.js:2284
    _getVectorTilePromise Leaflet.VectorGrid.bundled.js:2278
    _getVectorTilePromise Leaflet.VectorGrid.bundled.js:2277
    promise callback*_getVectorTilePromise/< Leaflet.VectorGrid.bundled.js:2273
    promise callback*_getVectorTilePromise Leaflet.VectorGrid.bundled.js:2267
    createTile Leaflet.VectorGrid.bundled.js:1988
    _addTile GridLayer.js:810
    _update GridLayer.js:713
    _setView GridLayer.js:574
    _resetView GridLayer.js:530
    onAdd GridLayer.js:162
    _layerAdd Layer.js:114
    whenReady Map.js:1477
    addLayer Layer.js:172
    addTo Layer.js:52
    <anonymous> index.html:91

I have also tried this with https://unpkg.com/Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles@1.0.0/Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles.js but then I get no error and no output.
How can I display mbtiles in a leaflet map?

Your vector tiles are probably zipped, but L.vectorGrid.protobuf does not support zipped tiles. When you unpack mbtiles, unpack to unzipped .pbf tiles. See https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/issues/121

unfortunately, this is not my issue. I've added more info to the question, but to summarize, I have a SQLite db of premade tiles from https://github.com/lukasmartinelli/naturalearthtiles/releases/tag/v1.0

You write " I have a SQLite db of premade tiles". How do you know these tiles are not zipped? Have you checked individual tile?

When I converted natural_earth.vector.mbtiles to individual tiles with MapTiler Engine, specifying no compression for tiles, I had no problem displaying them with L.vectorGrid.protobuf. This tells that the problem are definitely compressed tiles.

Do you have suggestions on how I can uncompressed these tiles? They are stored as a blob in the sqlite db. Protobuf itself is highly compressed, so I am not sure why they have compressed them further. In any case, how can I uncompress the tiles after SELECTing them from the database?

On possibility to extract uncompressed tiles from .mbtiles is MapTiler Engine (https://www.maptiler.com/engine/download/), but free version has limitations on number of vector features (1000). I tried it on natural_earth.vector.mbtiles and was then able to display exported vector tiles with  L.vectorGrid.protobuf.

thanks. I was finally able to uncompress the tiles using node's built in unzip capabilities. Works quite well. Also, turns out the raster tiles are not compressed and work out of the box. I am gonna write up my experience building a tiny tile server

@TomazicM was correct… the vector tiles in the db I downloaded were indeed compressed. I was able to uncompress them on the fly. I am using Bun to build my tiny tile server, and the following did the trick
const db = new Database(
    'path/to/natural_earth.vector.mbtiles', 
    { strict: true }
);
const res = db.query('SELECT tile_data AS tile FROM tiles WHERE zoom_level = $z AND tile_column = $x AND tile_row = $y').get({ z, x, y });

if (res) {

    const data = Buffer.from(res.tile);

    // => Uint8Array
    return Bun.gunzipSync(data);
}

